How does Heidegger account for the imagination and mental images in his monism?
Heidegger purportedly does away with subject-object dualism with his monism of being-in-the-world.
But my mental image of a neon green cobra with a checkered cape is nowhere to be found in the "background of skilled coping" or in my expert non-mental manipulation of a hammer.
Is Heidegger just minimizing and making secondary the cognition of arbitrary representations? If so, that's interesting, but its still a dualism.

It is a distinction, but I am not convinced that it is a dualism as we have been using the term.

The existence of mental neon green cobras happens within Dasein's existence.
Also, a hammer may exists in your existence and it may exist in my existence. It may exist in our existence(s), but for short we just say the hammer exists and overlook the phenomenon of being-in-the-world.
It is normal for Dasein to ignore its own existence: "Being loves to hide".

Heraclitus (fragment 123): phusis krupteshai philei: Being …
intrinsically inclines toward self-concealment. IM 120-1

So in this case the primary cognition is "here is my hammer". But upon existential reflection the hammer is in the world which Dasein existingly is—subject and world together.

That inside which one primarily understands oneself has Dasein’s kind
of Being. Dasein is its world existingly.
SZ 364

That is not to say all undiscovered hammers exists in one's being-in-the-world, except perhaps in the notional set of undiscovered things.
When, we say the hammer is and Dasein is, thereby treating Dasein as present-at-hand, these existing entities are both grounded by existence—by 'Being', whatever unique concept that entails.

‘Being’ cannot … be conceived as an entity; enti non additur
aliqua natura: nor can it acquire such a character as to have the
term “entity” applied ‘to it. “Being” cannot be derived from higher
concepts by definition, nor can it be presented through lower ones.
SZ 4

However, Being-in-the-world is more tangible: It is Dasein's primary kind of existence (as opposed to being present-at-hand) and is not dual.

The compound expression 'Being-in-the-world' indicates in the very way
we have coined it, that it stands for a unitary phenomenon. This
primary datum must be seen as a whole.
SZ 53

Among the modes of being-in-the-world is understanding, knowing, seeing and imagining.

'understanding' in the sense of one possible kind of cog­nizing
among others (as distinguished, for instance, from 'explaining'),
must, like explaining, be Interpreted as an existential derivative of
that primary understanding which is one of the constituents of the
Being of the "there" in general.
SZ 143

Hopefully that helps to some extent.
